# Block duplicate data in table Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to block equal data entry in the phone number.

I tried several methods and failed.

I changed the code several times and I couldn't.

```
`const form = document.getElementById('agenda-de-contatos');
let linhas = [];
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputNomeContato = document.getElementById('nome-do-contato');
    const inputNumeroTelefone = document.getElementById('numero-de-telefone');
    
    if (linhas.includes(inputNumeroTelefone.value)) {
        alert(`Número: ${inputNumeroTelefone.value} já foi inserido`);
    } else {
        linhas.push(inputNumeroTelefone.value);
    }
        
    let linha = '<tr>';
    linha += `<td>${inputNomeContato.value}</td>`;
    linha += `<td>${inputNumeroTelefone.value}</td>`;
    linha += `<td><button class='excluir' onclick="deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex,this)">Remover</button></td>`;
    linha += '</tr>';
    
    linhas.push(linha);
     
    const corpoTabela = document.querySelector('tbody');
    corpoTabela.innerHTML = linhas.join("")
})
 
function deleteRow(id,node) {
   
 linhas.splice(id-1,1);
    document.getElementById('tabela').deleteRow(id);
  
}`
```

Comment: if you already use backticks - then why do you repeat a variable and push it to an array instead of writing the entire block into a single backtick block?

Comment: I nei do it, how do you do it?

Comment: https://codepen.io/tacoshy/pen/KKemdMj -> Backticks allow the string to be written in multiple lines.

Comment: I made the change tacoshy
 , but it continues to register the same phone numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a little confusion in your script, as to what you want to keep in `linhas`. You pushed both, a phone number and a whole `<tr>`-html code into it. I changed it so that you only have the telephone numbers in it (your HTML markup was missing, so I just made it up):

```js
const form = document.getElementById('agenda-de-contatos'),
  corpoTabela = document.querySelector('tbody'),
  linhas = [];

corpoTabela.onclick=ev=>{
 if (ev.target.tagName=="BUTTON"){
   const tr=ev.target.closest("tr");
   linhas.splice(tr.rowIndex-1,1);
   tr.remove();
   console.log(linhas);
}}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const inputNomeContato = document.getElementById('nome-do-contato');
  const phoneInp = document.getElementById('numero-de-telefone').value, phone=phoneInp.replace(/[\s()-]/g,"");

  if (linhas.includes(phone)) {
    alert(`Número: ${phoneInp} já foi inserido`);
  } else {
    linhas.push(phone);
    corpoTabela.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<tr>
    <td>${inputNomeContato.value}</td>
    <td>${phoneInp}</td>
    <td><button class='excluir'>Remover</button></td>
   </tr>`);
   console.log(linhas);
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="agenda-de-contatos">
  <input id="nome-do-contato" placeholder="Name?"><input id="numero-de-telefone" placeholder="Phone number?">
  <button>submit</button>
</form>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone Number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

After reading @EssXTee's comment regarding the formatting of phone numbers I decided to sanitise the input values before pushing them onto `linhas`:

```
phone=phoneInp.replace(/[\s()-]/g,"")
```

This should make the comparison a little more robust.

Answer (score 0):

The only real issue with your code not working is that you just need to exit your function when you detect a duplicate phone number. It seems your code currently alerts if a duplicate number is detected, but because there is no `return` statement, the function will continue to execute code (*thus adding the new entry to the table*).

There are a few other things that could be adjusted with your code, like *tacoshy* mentioned you don't need to concatenate a new string variable when using backticks. Another seems to be that your `deleteRow()` function doesn't work (*and appears to call itself which could be bad*).

Your HTML was not provided so I included the bare minimum for a code snippet to show the fixes.

```js
let linhas = []

document.getElementById('agenda-de-contatos').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()

  const inputNomeContato = document.getElementById('nome-do-contato'),
        inputNumeroTelefone = document.getElementById('numero-de-telefone')

  if(linhas.some(l => l.includes(inputNumeroTelefone.value))) {
    alert(`Número: ${inputNumeroTelefone.value} já foi inserido`)
    return
  }

  linhas.push(`<tr>
      <td>${inputNomeContato.value}</td>
      <td>${inputNumeroTelefone.value}</td>
      <td><button class='excluir' onclick="deleteRow(this)">Remover</button></td>
    </tr>`)

  document.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML = linhas.join("")
})

function deleteRow(id) {
  linhas.splice(id.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex,1)
  document.querySelector('tbody').innerHTML = linhas.join("")
}
```

```html
<form id="agenda-de-contatos">
  <input id="nome-do-contato" type="text" placeholder="Name"><br>
  <input id="numero-de-telefone" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

#### NOTES

One unusual thing I noticed is that you are pushing both the phone number and your HTML into the same array. I'm not sure if that is intentional because it causes your phone number to display twice (once above the row and once properly in the actual table column). You could just use 2 arrays (one with the phone numbers only and one with the HTML), however you are able to just store the HTML and check if that contains duplicate phone numbers using `some()` on the array.

Comment: You are checking the phone numbers inside an HTML markup string using the `.includes()` method. This will cause a few rejections that might not be anticipated. For example the number "23456" would be rejected, if a number "12345678" had been entered before.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann That is a fair assumption, but given the lack of details outlined by OP, I'm not sure if it will matter. There is no established phone number format for validation, which there should be and would alleviate most issues that might be caused by checking for phone numbers using `includes()`. Without the validation one user may input "1234567890" while another may input "(123)456-7890", which would not be caught either. The same goes for the lack of parenthesis but a dash is kept, spaces, etc.